# Save samba file operation logs

Tags: server, samba

I’m setting up samba on an Ubuntu server. I need to keep records of file operations for 90 days. How can I set this up? All I can find is a log size setting. Don’t really want 100meg log files, and it seems to say it saves the main log and one previous before overwriting? I may be reading things wrong.